# What are all possible values for the 'Type=' option in a .desktop service file in KDE/Dolphin's?

Tags: kde, .desktop, plasma5, servicemenu

In application launchers that I have seen is `Type=Application`, in Dolphin actions (that I can create in `~/.local/share/kservices5`) it is `Type=Service`.

Are there other possibilities beside these two for Dolphin and KDE/Plasma 5?

The context in which this interests me is that of a more specific question that I have posted at the same time:

[How many sub-levels can there be in Dolphin actions/services?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/343211/32012)

but slso [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10586/170) on elementaryOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Glorious [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries) has an answer and more detailed information about that.

The [freedesktop.org specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#value-types) consist of three .desktop Types:

- **Application**: a shortcut to an application
- **Link**: a shortcut to a web link.
- **Directory**: a container of meta data of a menu entry

The [KDE techbase](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Desktop_File) mentions one extra type:

- **Service**: an entry of the context menu, when you right-click a file or directory in your file manager

Comment: what about `Type=Service`?

Comment: @cipricus - that's prolly part of a dolphin menu service... anyway to answer your question, yes, the possibilities are countless because basically anyone can implement and support their own `Type` which will (almost always) be ignored by other implementations

Comment: As the don said, these are custom specifications, which will be recognized from different software (probably DE). I just showed you what the freedesktop specifications had in mind. You can write your own software, that needs to read `Type=cipricus`, for example, which then won't be recognized by "normal" software. :-)

Comment: @don_crissti - I think I should edit the question, as it seems that what I am looking for is not only limited to the freedesktop, but even KDE-specific

Comment: It seems like `Type=Service` is there only exception. Read in the [KDE pages](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Desktop_File). :-) After that, they refer to the page in my answer.

Comment: Edited my answer to your edited question.

Comment: Also `Type=Action`, in desktop files (containing GConf settings) created  in `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions` when I add Nautilus actions with `nautilus-actions-config-tool`, which then appear in PCManFM, as indicated [here](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM#Add_own_options_to_the_files_context_menu). That doesn't seem to be specified anywhere in the posted links: [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys) there is *Action* as a key, but not as an option for the `Type` key.

Comment: In fact, when creating multi-sub-menus with the nautilus config tool, the lowest levels (the actions themselves) are of the type "action", but the intermediary steps which are configurations in Gconf, contain another option that was not yet mentioned , `Type=Menu`. See http://askubuntu.com/a/881124/47206